# Updating the selected items in my API for the object array is not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I want to update the state of my API.
I have an array of objects items that i want to select from the UI and then click on the submit button to save them.

Comment: try to add your source code

Comment: please send me your email to contact you. And to send you the api data with the source code

Comment: @Abbass: Please add relevant code snippets to your question here, that is why we use StackOverflow :) Please read on tips on asking a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask